# Apparent bug with the --inspect-functions flag

Tags: google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

Based on some quick searching, it doesn't look like this issue has been reported yet.

This occurs when locally testing in a firebase functions project with two or more http functions defined for different paths, when supplying the --inspect-functions flag in this command:

```
firebase emulators:start --only functions --inspect-functions
```

After a function is called for the first time, the mapping of http paths to functions is broken.  Every subsequent call to any function path will be routed to the first function that was called, rather than the one that corresponds to that path.

Minimal code to reproduce:  https://github.com/johnang3/functions-emulator-bug-demo

This occurs when using version 10.2.1 of the firebase CLI with firebase-functions versions 3.13.2 and 3.18.1.  I have not tested any other versions.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using an outdated version of `firebase-tools`.

I've tried running the command below under the functions directory, then tried running the browsers found in your Github, and it works fine on my end.

`npm install -g firebase-tools`